# How to add to website source code if it matches a certain page?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

at my school many websites are blocked. I am not interested in unblocking them but I looked at the source code of the block page.

The URL stays the same but the source code is obviously different.

After looking at the source code I found that is shows some useful information (such as reason for block, website category etc)

I am not great at coding so I am sorry if this is a bad question.

I have done some research but couldn't find any matches.

Anyway what I want to do is if the source code contains a certain snippet of code (present only on the 'Site Blocked' page), add some stuff on the end about why it is blocked (this information is in the source code but as an HTML comment)

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm. I think you really can't control that. What happens is the server of your internet is blocked by the IT's of your school. So before it is passed to you, it goes through them and if it passes through the router and detects it, it will return to you that blocked page you are saying.

**EDIT**

After reading through it, My answer would be nothing would be possible. I have moderate training with routers, advanced in html/php and from what I can asses, this is really blocked through the router and changing something in that HTML code would do nothing as it is processed already.

Comment: Ok, but is it possible to add to that blocked page? The only thing that changes is the comment at the end of the page

Comment: Can you give us a sample of the source of that page? Or that comment? I'll edit my answer again if needed

Comment: Thanks @WillBishop, I updated my answer though it's almost the same as the first one. But this time I have read through your code.

Comment: Did i somehow answer your question? If yes if you an give me an upvote or maybe even check my answer. Thanks @WillBishop